# How to Draw Kundli Design (diamonds and triangles in square) using HTML and CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to draw a Kundli Design using HTML and CSS. I tried it using simple tables but its didn't work. here is my code for it.

**Fiddle Link**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLOGVp

**Kundli Design (which I want to achieve)**
[image]

**HTML**

```
        <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <table border="1" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td>1<br />ABC<br />123<br />!@#$</td>
            <td>2<br />ABC<br />123</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3<br />ABC<br />123</td>
            <td>4<br />ABC<br />123</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <table border="1" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td>9<br />ABC<br />123</td>
            <td>10<br />ABC<br />123<br />!@#$</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>11<br />ABC<br />123</td>
            <td>12<br />ABC<br />123</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <table border="1" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td>5<br />ABC<br />123<br />!@#$</td>
            <td>6<br />ABC<br />123<br />!@#$</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8<br />ABC<br />123</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal myModal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use svg?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
.main {
            height: 250px;
            width: 250px;
            border: 3px solid #000;
            margin: 100px auto;
            float: none;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        
        .sub {
            height: 175px;
            width: 175px;
            border: 3px solid #000;
            transform: rotate(45deg);
            margin-left: 37px;
            margin-top: 37px;
        }
        
        .line1 {
            height: 10px;
            width: 360px;
            border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
            transform: rotate(135deg);
            margin-top: -95px;
            margin-left: -50px;
        }
        
        .line2 {
            height: 10px;
            width: 380px;
            border-top: 3px solid #000;
            transform: rotate(-135deg);
            margin-left: -50px;
            margin-top: -10px;  
        }
        p{
            margin: 0;
        }
        .p1{
            margin-top: -130px;
            margin-left: 50px;
        }
        .p2{
            margin-top: -35px;
            margin-left: 180px;
        }
        .p3{
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
        .p4{
            margin-top: -35px;
            margin-left: 110px;
        }
        .p5{
            margin-top: -35px;
            margin-left: 215px;
        }
        .p6{
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-left: 45px;
        }
        .p7{
            margin-top: -35px;
            margin-left: 170px;
        }
        .p8{
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
        .p9{
            margin-top: -35px;
            margin-left: 110px;
        }
        .p10{
            margin-top: -35px;
            margin-left: 215px;
        }
        .p11{
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-left: 50px;
        }
        .p12{
            margin-top: -35px;
            margin-left: 180px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="main">
        <div class="sub"></div>
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        
        <p class="p1">AA<br>&nbsp;01</p>
        <p class="p2">AA<br>&nbsp;02</p>
        <p class="p3">AA<br>&nbsp;03</p>
        <p class="p4">AA<br>&nbsp;04</p>
        <p class="p5">AA<br>&nbsp;05</p>
        <p class="p6">AA<br>&nbsp;06</p>
        <p class="p7">AA<br>&nbsp;07</p>
        <p class="p8">AA<br>&nbsp;08</p>
        <p class="p9">AA<br>&nbsp;09</p>
        <p class="p10">AA<br>&nbsp;10</p>
        <p class="p11">AA<br>&nbsp;11</p>
        <p class="p12">AA<br>&nbsp;12</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Great work, but did you see my fiddle output ? Where I place content ?

Comment: I allready post image in question, still here is link with text in it. Please note that text may be different http://www.astrosage.com/kundli/images/janam-kundli.jpg

Comment: Yes..u posted image...but was jus for design purpose..i wanted to know how your data would be displayed...Give me some time..

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be hard to achieve this with a `<table>`. Use multiple div and position them.

Here a little help :

```css
body{
padding:50px;  
}

.container:{
position:relative;
}

.losange{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:solid 1px black;
transform:rotate(45deg);
position:absolute;
top:22px;
}

.triangle{
border-top:solid 1px black;
position:absolute;;
overflow:hidden;
width:142px;
height:100px;
top:0px;
left:110px;
}

.triangle div{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:solid 1px black;
transform:rotate(45deg);
top:-50px;
left:20px;
position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="losange"></div>

    <div class="triangle"><div></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Alexis, let me try this to set trianle in square as I want.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is probably using svg. Here is an example

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

line {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg height="200" width="200">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200"/>
  <line x1="200" y1="0" x2="0" y2="200"/>
  <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="100" y2="0"/>
  <line x1="100" y1="200" x2="200" y2="100"/>
  <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="200" y2="100"/>
  <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="100" y2="200"/>
</svg>
```

I also had a play around with using divs and transforms like Alexis suggested but it was much trickier. Here is where I got to, from this point it is just adjusting the translate numbers.

```css
div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.even .f {
  transform: translate(-6px,3px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.odd .f {
  transform: translate(3.5px,-7.5px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.even .b {
  transform: translate(-10.5px,3px) rotate(45deg);
}

.odd .b {
  transform: translate(-20px,-7.5px) rotate(45deg);
}

.trail {
  transform: translate(0,-21.5px);
}

.f, .b {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="even">
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="f"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="f"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="odd">
    <div class="f"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="f"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="even trail">
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="f"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="f"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="odd trail">
    <div class="f"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="f"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, But how I can put text and ids inside triangles in your SVG example. Because I also want click event on it.

Comment: You could use polygons with borders instead of lines if you like. have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_polygon.asp). That way you can put <text> elements in them and add click events.

Answer (score 1):

I know Its very Late To answer this question but the best option to draw kundli design is svg, you can use polygon in svg

```html
          <svg
            style="
          
              outline: 1px solid red;
            "
            height="800"
            width="780"
            rx="15"
            ry="15"
          >
            <!-- house 1 -->
            <polygon
              points="400 100,250 250,400 400,550 250"
              style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1"
              id="house1"
              ng-click="alert()"
            />

            <!-- house 2 -->
            <polygon
              style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1"
              points="100 100, 250 250,400 100"
              id="house2"
            />

            <!-- house 3  -->
            <polygon
              points="100 400,250 250,100 100"
              style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1"
              id="house3"
            />

            <!-- house 4 -->
            <polygon
              points="250 250,100 400,250 550,400 400"
              style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1"
              id="house4"
            />

            <!--house 5  -->
            <polygon
              points="100 400,250 550,100 700"
              style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1"
              id="house5"
            />
            <!-- house 6 -->
            <polygon
              points="100 700,250 550,400 700"
              style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1"
              id="house6"
            />

            <!-- house 7 -->
            <polygon
              points="400 400,250 550,400 700,550 550"
              style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1"
              id="house7"
            />

            <!-- house 8 -->
            <polygon
              points="400 700,550 550,700 700"
              style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1"
              id="house8"
            />

            <!-- house 9 -->
            <polygon
              points="700 400,550 550,700 700"
              style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1"
              id="house9"
            />

            <!-- house 10 -->
            <polygon
              points="550 250,700 400,550 550,400 400"
              style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1"
              id="house10"
            />

            <!--house 11  -->
            <polygon
              points="700 100,550 250,700 400"
              style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1"
              id="house11"
            />

            <!-- house 12 -->
            <polygon
              points="400 100,550 250,700 100"
              style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1"
              id="house12"
            />


          </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jCanvas](http://projects.calebevans.me/jcanvas/) (jQuery drawing library), [how to draw paths](http://projects.calebevans.me/jcanvas/docs/paths/) in particular.

You have to add a `canvas` element and draw on it using JavaScript.

[see example here](http://projects.calebevans.me/jcanvas/sandbox/?code=Ly8gRHJhdyBhIGZhY2Ugd2l0aCB0aGUgamF3IGRpc2Nvbm5lY3RlZAokKCdjYW52YXMnKS5kcmF3UGF0aCh7CiAgc3Ryb2tlU3R5bGU6ICcjMDAwJywKICBzdHJva2VXaWR0aDogNCwKICBwMTogewogICAgdHlwZTogJ2xpbmUnLAogICAgeDE6IDIwMCwgeTE6IDUwLAogICAgeDI6IDEwMCwgeTI6IDE1MCwKICAgIHgzOiAyMDAsIHkzOiAxNTAsCiAgICB4NDogMTIwLCB5NDogMjAwCiAgfSwKICBwMjogewogICAgdHlwZTogJ3F1YWRyYXRpYycsCiAgICB4MTogMTMwLCB5MTogMjEwLAogICAgY3gxOiAxODAsIGN5MTogMjUwLAogICAgeDI6IDIyNSwgeTI6IDIwMAogIH0KfSk7)

Comment: He can achieve this without canvas

Comment: @Alexis What is the disadvantage of using a canvas in this case?

Comment: Don't say it's a disavantage, but he have not ask for how to achieve this with a canvas. And i've just say it can be done without.

Comment: He put javascript and jquery as tags so why not propose a javascript solution?

Comment: @elementzero23 Yes, each block has click even on it (open bootstrap model)

Comment: OK, then it's easier to generate divs and rotate them, just as Alexis suggested